# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential) in multivariate prediction

Tags: python, error-handling, reshape, prediction

i have ran these code to train for model of LSTM multivariate attribute, it will predict "rain", "humidity" , "pressure" in 1 model, but then i receive this error:
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).

```
Input 0 of layer "lstm_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (32, 10)

Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 30, 3), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.ERROR)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.read_csv('D:/ĐỒ ÁN TRÍ TUỆ NHÂN TẠO/HCM_weather.csv')
#print(df.head(10))

dataset = df[['rain' , 'humidi', 'pressure' ,'date']]
dataset.set_index('date', inplace=True)
dataset = dataset.reset_index(drop=True)
training_set = dataset.iloc[:, [0,1,2]].values
#print(training_set[:10])

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)
#print(training_set_scaled[:10])

x_train = []
y_train = []
n_future = 4  # Dự báo độ ẩm 4 ngày tới
n_past = 30  # 30 ngày trước

for i in range(n_past, len(training_set_scaled) - n_future +1):
    x_train.append(training_set_scaled[i - n_past:i, :])
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i:i + n_future, :])

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Bidirectional

regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_past, dataset.shape[1]))))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.25))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=10, return_sequences=False))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.25))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=10, return_sequences=False))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.25))
regressor.add(LSTM(units=10))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.25))
regressor.add(Dense(units=n_future * 3, activation='relu'))
regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

# Train the model
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1)

testdataset = pd.read_csv('D:/ĐỒ ÁN TRÍ TUỆ NHÂN TẠO/HCM_weather.csv')
testdataset = testdataset.iloc[:30, [5,6,7]].values
real_humidity = pd.read_csv('D:/ĐỒ ÁN TRÍ TUỆ NHÂN TẠO/HCM_weather.csv')
real_humidity = real_humidity.iloc[30:, [5,6,7]].values

# Assuming 'testdataset' contains the data for the test set
testing = sc.transform(testdataset)
testing = np.array(testing)
testing = np.reshape(testing, (1, n_past, 3))

predicted_values = []  # List to store the predictions

for i in range(30):
    # Predict the next 'n_future' time steps
    prediction = regressor.predict(testing)

    # Store the prediction
    predicted_values.append(prediction[0])

    # Convert the prediction to a 3D array to update 'testing'
    prediction_3d = prediction.reshape(1, -1, 3)

    # Remove the oldest time step from 'testing' and add the prediction
    testing = np.concatenate((testing[:, n_future:, :], prediction_3d), axis=1)
    testing = testing.reshape(1, n_past, 3)  # Reshape to 3D





predicted_values = np.array(predicted_values)
predicted_values = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_values)
predicted_values = np.reshape(predicted_values, (predicted_values.shape[0], predicted_values.shape[1] // 3 , 3))

print(predicted_values)
print()
print(predicted_values.size)
print()
print(predicted_values.shape)

#real_humidity = real_humidity[:120]

#predicted_values = predicted_values.reshape(120,1)
#mplt.plot(predicted_values , label = 'predicted')
#mplt.plot(real_humidity , label = 'real value')

#mplt.legend()
#mplt.show()
```

it's error in the confict of input shape of LSTM model , it should be 3, instead of 2, but i don't know where the error come from, can you guy help me